# Slide view over status bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

I have a root UIPageViewController with two subview controllers, one of which (ViewA) shows the status bar and the other (ViewB) does not.  I currently have each view controller change the status bar shown/hidden in viewWillAppear, but this results in the status bar jerking whenever you start to slide between views.  I'd like to have ViewB appear to slide over the status bar when you swipe it in (like how Snapchat's camera view does).  Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `windowLevel` of the `UIWindow` which contains that `UIViewController`.

You're going to end up with two `UIWindow`s, which is possible.

This blog post had a great explanation *and* sample code for how it's achieved:

[How to Build the Facebook Paper Status Bar Hover](http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2014/02/07/how-to-build-the-facebook-paper-status-bar-hover/)

[image: Facebook Paper example]

[image]

Comment: Thanks runmad, but UIPageViewController won't accept UIWindows as subviews (it crashes), so this won't for my use case. I guess I could rebuild a custom version of UIPageViewController, but I decided to just fix the navbar frame of the view that has the status bar so it doesn't jump instead.